# Item was not crawled because of a password change. Update password and retry crawling

Tags: 2010, search

We are crawling our website for 1st time, but we got this error in the log of sharepoint search.

Also in the event log we have this warning

The start address http://xxx

Context: Application 'Search_Service_Application', Catalog 'Portal_Content'

Details:
    Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.   (0x8007052e)

We havent change any password in any service accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the domain accounts used for Search and for Crawling are not disabled or set to 'Require password change at first logon'

You can also check the accounts by trying to run something under that ID/PWD, such as Notepad.  Simply hold shift down when you right click on a shortcut to notepad and select "Run as Different User" and then enter the credentials.  If there is a problem with the accounts themselves, this should show you what it is.

If the above works properly then you might need to make sure that your crawl account has Read permissions to the site in the *Web Application Policy* in Central Admin